# Show alert when a button click for second time in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a button and I want to show an alert when user click on the button for second time. Actually I want to disable second click on a button and show error alert !

How can I do this with JavaScript ?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: To get you started: search for mouse button events and javascript ...

Comment: you'll want to add a hidden field to track the number of times the button has been clicked, and tie an event handler to your button.  on click, check the value of your hidden field.  if it's greater than 1, show an alert.  if it's not, then update the value of the hidden field.

Answer (score 2):

Having this button in your HTML

```
<button onclick="whichClick()">Click me</button>
```

You can add a class on your first click and then check is the class is already present, so you can throw the error:

```
function whichClick(e) {
    if (e.target.className.contains('clicked')) {
       alert("error");
    } else {
       e.target.className.addClass('clicked');
    }
}
```